# EclipseLink Cache is not refreshed correctly in Cache Coordination

Tags: eclipselink

I'm trying to build cache coordination with eclipselink and here is the issue. There is a table in db which have *NAME* and *CHECK_TIME* columns. My first application have FULL cache and with *getAll()* it loads all values to cache from DB in the begining. After that prints objects with `get("name_"+i)` in loop as `[name_1,2014-07-04 00:00:00],[name_2,2014-07-04 00:00:00]` and so on .

There is a second application which are using same cache, thanks to cache coordination, and update CHECK_TIME values with *merge()* and I can see these new values in db. So this second app check a line in each second and update *CHECK_TIME* column.

After second application is starting, first application prints still old CHECK_TIME values **even rmi log says objects are merged**. So I think that cache coordination is not working at first, however, if I tried to create a new object with *persist()* like `[new_name_1,2014-07-04 16:43:32]` in second app, then first application printed it to screen immediately that means cache is refreshed correctly.

Do you know why `get('name_'+i)` return always old value even cache is refreshed? It is like there is a secondary cache in eclipselink.

**persistence.xml**

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol" value="rmi" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.naming-service" value="rmi" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.rmi.url" value="rmi://$HOST:1090" />
```

**Subsciber.java**

```
@NamedQueries({
               @NamedQuery(name = "get", query = "select b from Subscriber b where b.name = :name ", hints = {
                                                                                                                            @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_TYPE, value = QueryType.ReadObject),
                                                                                                                            @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, value = CacheUsage.CheckCacheOnly)}),
               @NamedQuery(name = "getAll", query = "select b from Subscriber b ", hints = {
                                                                                                    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_TYPE, value = QueryType.ReadAll),
                                                                                                    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, value = CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache)})})
@Cache(type = CacheType.FULL, coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES)
```

**Edit:**

```
private SubscriberIdentity get(String name) {
    SubscriberIdentity result = null;
    try {
        //entityManager is global
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("get");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        result = (SubscriberIdentity) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof NoResultException || e instanceof NoResultException) {
            //TODO
        } 

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you reusing a single EntityManager?  There are two levels of caching in JPA - a shared cache at the serverSession/EntityManagerFactory level (aka second level cache) and a cache at the UnitOfWork/EntityManager level (first level cache).  The first level cache is kept separate from the second and works like a transaction.  Cache coordination works at the shared cache level, as the EntityManager cache is meant to act as a transaction, and not be long lived.

Comment: @Chris yes actually I'm using same EntityManager again and again. I've try adding em.refresh(object) after getter and it works! but if I'm not wrong refresh() access to db, so if I'm using it then advantage of using cache will disappear?

Comment: yes, refresh forces a database hit.  Clear your EM or close and reobtain the EM at points where you no longer need to track changes as caching managed entities in the EM adds overhead that you might not need all the time, and contributes to your stale data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Chris big help in comments, I understand that the problem is using static entityManager object because it use own cache instead of checking shared cache in case of second call for *get(name_1)*. So I changed

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("get");
```

part as

```
EntityManager em = new EntityManager();
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("get");
```

in getter and cache coordination works truely for UPDATE case too.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris said, and you can also check the document [EL Cache](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching):

> By default EclipseLink uses a shared object cache, that caches a
>   subset of all objects read and persisted for the persistence unit. The
>   EclipseLink shared cache differs from the local EntityManager cache.
>   The shared cache exists for the duration of the persistence unit
>   (EntityManagerFactory, or server) and is shared by all EntityManagers
>   and users of the persistence unit. The local EntityManager cache is
>   not shared, and only exists for the duration of the EntityManager or
>   transaction.

The limitation of the shared cache, is that if the database is changed directly through JDBC, or by another application or server, the objects in the shared cache will be stale.

EclipseLink offers several mechanism to deal with stale data including:

- Refreshing
- Invalidation
- Optimistic locking
- **Cache coordination**